# How to effectively monetize a facebook page

Tags: small-business, business

I have a facebook page with an increasing number of likes. I would like to find a way to make money out of it.

Since the page is about a niche subject (photos of a city), I'm thinking about using a service like Shopify to sell t-shirts related to this.

Do you have any other suggestion on how to monetize the page?

In addition, do you know when it would be best to start monetizing?

For instance, in order to maximize the sales of t-shirts it would be useful to know when it's the best time to publicize the products: peak of reached users? Peak of engaged users? Is 1000 likes a good starting point or would it be wiser to wait for more likes?

Those are all examples of questions I have in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Very good question Cress

first of all bild a strong comunity and then ask then! maybe t-shirts are fine but tea cups will be awesome?!

Really, they know what they wont from you and take they opinion in consideration.

There are two ways for getting paid one face-book one you sell your stuff second you sell other people stuff.

If you do nice photos consider first sell your stuff to your audience putting in your posts advertise for that. Unlike other platforms that you get paid indirectly from advertisers on face-book you can contract directly with your advertisers. I'm at that process too so very good luck